# Comparing 2 datasets using ==

Tags: dataframe, logical-operators

Newbie here.  I need to find similar, but not identical elements in two different data sets.  One dataset has a column that looks like this:

ENST00000265620

I want to find this element in another data set called GNAS_ENST using == but GNAS_ENST looks like this:

ENST00000265620.11    The following script does not work:

```
GNAS_ENST$transcript_id == "ENST00000265620"
```

I have used the grep command successfully, thinking a similar thing would work. Shown below

```
temp1[grep("^ENST[0-9]{11}.[0-9]{0-2}",GNAS_ENST$transcript_id),]
```

but when I try

```
GNAS_ENST$transcript_id == "ENST00000265620.[0-9]{0-2}"
```

and numerous variations on this theme it doesn't work. I do know that

```
GNAS_ENST$transcript_id == "ENST00000265620.11"
```

works.  I just need the function to ignore the .11 or .1 or .25 suffix's.  I could try and create a new dataset without the .11, but don't know how to remove this suffix.

Also,

```
"ENST00000265620" %in% GNAS_ENST
```

or vice versa doesn't work.  I think when I go to actually compare the two datasets I will use the %in% operator, but I'm just trying something simple first.

Any help for a newbie would be appreciated.